# not able to access the reduce method in reduce class

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reduce, reducers

```
 public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>
    {
        private Text txtReduceOutputKey = new Text("");
        private Text txtReduceOutputValue = new Text("");
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        //some code;
    }
}
```

It is not giving any error. I am able to access the class as I am able to initiate those variables `txtReduceOutputKey`  and `txtReduceOutputValue`. but the `reduce` method is ignored while execution. So I am not able to run the code //some code in the above method. Also I am using below packages.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
```

Any idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please make it sure that you have set the **Reducer class** in the driver code.
For example :-

```
job.setReducerClass(Base_Reducer.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Such issues come due to couple reasons like below:

1. Not overriding the `reduce()` method - it's better to annotate with `override`
2. As mentioned in an earlier comment, forgetting to set reducer in the driver code

Answer (score 0):

it was because of `Iterator`. it should be replaced by `Iterable`.
Thank you.